# Unable to update UI even when data of model changes (using Angular 4 - observables)

Tags: angular, angular-observable

1) I have SiteMap component that displays:
   a) 3 Buttons: Confirm, Upload File Again, Update UI (For testing)
   b) Component TreeView: this takes an array as an input and displays it
      on the UI.

```
<!--siteMap-component.html -->
<div class="tree">
  <tree-view [siteTree]="siteMapTree">

  </tree-view>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <button type="button" class="pull-right btn-primary" (click)="approveAndUploadLandingPages()">Confirm</button>
  <button type="button" class="pull-left btn-inverse" (click)="updateSiteMapTree()">Refresh UI</button>
  <button type="button" class="pull-left btn-inverse" (click)="uploadAgain()">Upload Again</button>
</div>
```

2) I have a siteMapDataObservable, that is initialized with a value. Now the value of this Observable is be updated whenever there is this.siteMapDataObservable.next() call from updateSiteMapTree().

```
// SitemapComponent
import ...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-gb-sitemap',
  templateUrl: './sitemap.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sitemap.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class SitemapComponent implements OnInit {

  siteMapTree: Array<any>;
  siteMapDataObservable: BehaviorSubject<Object> = new BehaviorSubject<Object>(this.contactServerService.getSiteMapObject());


  constructor(private contactServerService: ContactServerService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, public modal: Modal) {
  }

  updateSiteMapTree() {
    this.siteMapDataObservable.next(this.contactServerService.getSiteMapObject());// this.contactServerService.getSiteMapObject() retrieves the data from sessionStorage
  }

  uploadAgain() {
    return this.modal.open(CustomModalComponent,  overlayConfigFactory({ }, BSModalContext));
  }

  rejectUpload() {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    this.clearSessionStorage();
  }

  approveAndUploadLandingPages() {
    this.contactServerService.uploadLandingPages(this.landingPagesObj)
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.clearSessionStorage();
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        },
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
  }

  clearSessionStorage() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('siteMapTree');
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.siteMapDataObservable
      .subscribe(
        siteMapTreeObj => {
          this.siteMapTree = [siteMapTreeObj['tree']];
        }
    );
  }
}
```

3) Upload Again Button opens a modal; CustomModalComponent is used to take another file from user and in the callback of http, the data model is modified and a call to updateSiteMapTree() in SiteMapComponent is made to get the siteMapTree updated.

```
// CustomModalComponent
import ...
@Component({
  selector: 'modal-content',
  templateUrl: './custom-modal-sample.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [SitemapComponent],
  styleUrls: ['./custom-modal-sample.scss']
})


export class CustomModalComponent implements OnInit {
  fileTypes: Array<string>;

  private uploadExcelUrl: string;
  public uploaderExcel: FileUploader;

  constructor(private router: Router, public dialog: DialogRef<any>, private contactServerService: ContactServerService,
              private siteMapComponent: SitemapComponent) {
    this.fileTypes = ['.xls', '.xlsx'];

    this.uploadExcelUrl = this.contactServerService.getExcelUploadUrl();
    this.uploaderExcel = new FileUploader({url: this.uploadExcelUrl});
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.uploaderExcel.onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
      fileItem.remove();

      const RESPONSE_DATA = JSON.parse(response);
      sessionStorage.setItem('landingPagesTree', JSON.stringify(RESPONSE_DATA));

      dialogBox.dismiss();

    };

    this.siteMapComponent.updateSiteMapTree();
  }

  getNextRouteState() {
    return this.router;
  }

  clearError() {
    this.dialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Findings: 1) The call to updateSiteMapTree() in SiteMapComponent from CustomModalComponent updates the 'siteMapTree' but the change is not reflected in the UI.

2) For testing, I have a button Refresh UI in SiteMapComponent Component that also calls updateSiteMapTree(). However, clicking this button updates the UI.

**Question**:
1) Why is my UI not updating when I call updateSiteMapTree() in SiteMapComponent from CustomModalComponent even when my data model is changed.

2) How is the UI getting changed when I call updateSiteMapTree() in SiteMapComponent from a button click in the same component.

**EDIT:**
Adding TreeViewComponent

```
import ...;

@Component({
  selector: 'tree-view',
  templateUrl: './tree-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree-view.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class TreeViewComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() siteTree: Array<any>;

  warnings: Array<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.warnings = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges ( ...args: any[]) {
    console.log('OnChange');
    console.log(this.siteTree);
  }

  toggle(subtree) {
    subtree.showChild = !subtree.showChild;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tick()` method from `ApplicationRef` to force detection change.

```
@Injectable()
export class Service {

    constructor(private appref: ApplicationRef){}

    public someMethod():void {
          //some actions, ie pushing next value to observable
          this.appref.tick();
    } 
}
```

https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef

Comment: In SitemapComponent's 'updateSiteMapTree()' , I added this.appref.tick(); at the end. I added it at the end so that once my next() function invokes this.siteMapDataObservable.subscribe(), only then appref.tick() is called. But still UI is not getting updated.

Comment: Did you change detection strategy?

Comment: How/where should I change the detection strategy?

Comment: import { ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core'; @Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

Comment: I used the detection strategy but still, I am not able to update UI. However, I found few things. Please check the description I have added 'TreeViewComponent', it is the child Component responsible to generate the UI. The ngOnChange() in TreeViewComponent is only called when angular first renders the page. When I change the data model that is @Input for TreeViewComponent, the ngOnChange() is not called again. I believe this is the reason the UI is not getting updated. Currently I used appref.tick() in updateSiteMapTree() of SitemapComponent. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: And your UI doesn't update, even using appref.tick(), yup?